# How to preserve the timestamps generated for SNAPSHOT artifacts?

Tags: maven, deployment, jenkins, timestamp, snapshot

Currently a Maven build (inside Jenkins) is configured to deploy every artifact it builds (releases and snapshots) to a Nexus repository. Now I have to push some of those artifacts to application servers and thought of letting the target servers fetch them from Nexus - this is easy for releases but how can I reference the SNAPSHOT artifacts? Maven's deploy plugin adds a timestamp to make each artifact unique (which is good) but I couldn't find a way to get that generated timestamp for later use!

> *Quick Aside:* I plan to use the promoted builds plugin to start a script on the target server(s) which then in turn ask Nexus for the new artifact to deploy.

Does anybody know how I can make Maven say the timestamp it generates? Or do I really have to parse the whole output for `Uploaded: https://NEXUS_URL/content/repositories/snapshots/GROUP/ARTIFACT/VERSION/ARTIFACT-VERSION-TIMESTAMP-SUFFIX.TYPE`?

Comment: Are you interested in just the latest snapshots? Have you looked into the `maven-metadata.xml` files in your artifacts' snapshots directories?

Comment: See also [Introduction to the POM, Special Variables](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Available_Variables): `maven.build.timestamp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you do need to parse the output of the `deploy` goal.